# Jquery UI Tabs contents are not coming in Print

Tags: grails, plugins, printing, jquery-ui-tabs

in one of our grails appln we are printing some of the stuffs from jquery ui tabs. After applying grails ui-performance plugin I could not print the contents of all the tabs available in the webpage. Only the selected tab is being printed. We are using a "print.css" to print the contents of the page. Moreover in Dev mode I could print the tab contents as I wish...any pointer to solve this problem using a single 'print.css' will be highly appreciated. --- SiQH

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use:

```
.ui-tabs-nav { display: none; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: block !important; }
```

in your print.css. It's not perfect, because you don't get the tab caption as a title.

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. First rule works but only the active tab is shown in print preview.

Comment: @rtpHarry: What went wrong? Check this http://jsbin.com/otefil/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this problem before and the best solution is use

```
@media print { .ui-tabs-nav {display:none !important;}
```

The print print preview will still only show the active tab but when its sent to the printer all the tabs will print.